# Using Variables in a fill query in a TableAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I’m using C# and Winforms. I’m trying to make a report that gives a list of people that need to renew their memberships if they expire within a user supplied date range. I've got a connection to an Access file, and I'm trying to set up a fill query for a TableAdapter, and I can’t figure out how to put a variable in my "WHERE" clause. The below SQL works to do what I need but obviously I don’t want to hard code the dates. I would like to substitute the dates with the variables “fromDate” and “toDate”. How can I do this? Thanks.

```
SELECT   [Last Name], [First Name], [Renewal Date]
FROM     Members
WHERE    ([Renewal Date] >= #1/1/2000#) AND ([Renewal Date] <= #1/1/2012#)
ORDER BY [Renewal Date]
```

Comment: Is there any part of this question that applies to Access at all?

Comment: Using '#' character for date literal values in SQL code strongly suggests this is targeting the Access database engine.

Comment: @David: he said an access file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In access [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k14b54kc.aspx) you can find how to define in a query that a value will be used as a paramater.

[Here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article.aspx?ArticleID=26) you can find samples of how to set parameter values in .net.

Comment: That's good info jvanderh, But I'm looking for how to modify the SQL inside a TableAdapter. So all I really need is the SQL. Thanks.

Comment: @JimDel - jvanderth is totaly right. You should use the parametrized query in tableadapter and you should changed values in parameters.

Comment: @JimDel: you do _not_ want to modify the SQL. Use a parameterized query, and set the parameters.

Comment: I'm just a beginner and am having trouble finding a tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: I suppose it does jvanderh, I'm just having trouble implementing it. I guess I just need to do some more research around the topic. But thanks for getting me started.

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar thing this morning in a Typed Dataset. I wanted the tableadapter of the typed dataset to get only certain rows.  If you open the Typed Dataset in the designer, right-click on it, and choose Configure... you can adjust the Select query.  Add a "Where" part, and include your parameter like this:

select *
from shoes
where shoecolor = @ColorParameter

In code when you are using the tableadapter to fill the dataset, you'll be able to add the value to use for the parameter there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use TableAdapters, so I could be wrong in this, but you could try doing the following:

```
DateTime startDate = ...somedate;
DateTime endDate = ...somedate;
myTableAdapter.SelectCommand.Text = GetExpiringMembershipsSql(startDate, EndDate);

...

public static void GetExpiringMembershipsSql(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    string template = @"SELECT   [Last Name], [First Name], [Renewal Date]
FROM     Members
WHERE    ([Renewal Date] >= #{0}#) AND ([Renewal Date] <= #{1}#)
ORDER BY [Renewal Date]";

    return string.Format(template, startDate.ToShortDateString(), endDate.ToShortDateString());
}
```

This is a rather dirty approach and utilizing parameters would be better, but I'm not very familiar with how access handles parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In a DataSet's TableAdapter , for a Access database connexion , you use the below query if you need a filter parameter .

select var1,var2 from Table where var1 = ?

Cheers !